# POSTGRESQL: Using Values List in Delete

Tags: postgresql, delete

Based on the [PostgreSQL Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-values.html) it seems possible to use `VALUES` list as argument in Insert/Select/Update.

Is it possible to use it as argument in `DELETE` something like:

`delete from some_table where (col1, col2) in values(......);`

??

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `values` keyword when you use `IN`

```
delete from some_table 
where (col1, col2) in ( (1,2), (3,4) );
```